# Make a summary version of lecture notes

Tags: tcolorbox, external-files

My aim is to make a summary of my lecture notes. More precisely I would like to write in the same file (per chapter), the whole structure (section, sub-sections), and then:

- by default the `tcolorbox` (definitions / theorems), and be able to put an optional parameter which says that this `tcolorbox` must not be copied.
- Same thing for the remarks: I would like that by default it is not copied, but I would like to give myself the possibility of doing it too.

I don't know what the best approach is to do all of this.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[skins,breakable,xparse,many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%ENV 1
\NewDocumentCommand\DefinirTheoreme{m m m m m m}{%
    \DeclareTColorBox[auto counter,
        number within       = chapter,
        crefname            = {#5}{#6}]{#1}{ o o }{
        enhanced,
        top                 = 2mm,
        coltitle            = #3,
        colframe            = #4,
        colbacktitle        = white,
        boxrule             = 0.5pt,
        toprule at break    = 0mm,
        bottomrule at break = 0mm,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.1in,xshift=0.2in},
        IfValueTF={##1}{title=#2 \thetcbcounter {~|~} {\color{black}\normalfont\bfseries ##1}}{title=#2 \thetcbcounter},
        IfValueTF={##2}{##2}{},
        }
   }%
%
\DefinirTheoreme{defi}{Définition}{blue}{blue}{Définition}{Définitions}

%ENV 2
\newcounter{Rem}[section]
\setcounter{Rem}{0}
\newenvironment{rema}[1][\unskip]{%
    \refstepcounter{Rem}
    \par\vspace{\topsep}%
    \noindent\textcolor{blue}{\sffamily Remarque \thesection.\theRem\:---} \: \textcolor{blue}{#1}}{\smallskip}

%
\begin{document}

\section{The first section (WRITED)}

\begin{defi}[WRITED]
    An important definition. 
\end{defi}

\begin{rema}
    Not very important, it is not written in the resume file.
\end{rema}

\section{The first section (WRITED)}

\begin{defi}[not writed]
    an unnecessary definition for the resume file.
\end{defi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just `\newcommand\moretext[1]{}` in the preamble and  `\moretext{<your prescindable tcolorbox or whatever>}` for the short version or just add `#1` to the definition   (i.,e,  `\newcommand\morethings[1]{#1}`) to have the full version? Or `\newcommand\showthis{#1}` and `\newcommand\notshowthis{}` in case of variable sets of things to show or hide?

Comment: It might work. If not, is it possible to redisplay the elements I want to keep at the end of the chapter? rather than doing two different typesettings (one for each version).

Comment: If not...? Just try it. `:-)` A complete switch of document version is just add/remove `#1`, just one time.  If you find a simpler method, let me know.